# how to show top 10 records in a report

Tags: reporting

Is there a way to show top n records in a report output, based on a column value that is sorted in a desc order. Please suggest.

Here I'm using Joined report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited Answer:**

Available only for Tabular Reports:

You can set the maximum number of records to display in a tabular report by clicking Add | Row Limit in report builder. Set the number of rows, then choose a field to sort by, and the sort order. Limiting rows on a tabular report allows you to use it as a source report for dashboard table and chart components.

Link to Help article :
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_limiting.htm&language=en_US

Comment: but here i'm using joined report. Is it possible with that

Comment: No, We cannot add row limit to joined report, only tabular.